# Computing Lebesgue and Hausdorff Integrals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, hausdorff-measure

I am stuyding for the exam and I need a little help with the following:
Let $m^k$ denote the kth-Lebesgue measure and $H^k$ the kth-Hausdorff measure.
Let $f(x, y, z) = x^2y^3z^4$.
Calculate:
$$\int_Afdm^3$$ where $A=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} : 0 < x < y < z < 1\}$
and $$\int_BfdH^3$$where $B=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} : 0 < x = y < z < 1\}$
Here is my solution for the first one:

$A=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} : 0 < x < y < z < 1\} = \{x \in\mathbb{R} : 0 < x < y\}\times\{y \in\mathbb{R} : 0 < y < z\}\times\{z \in\mathbb{R} : 0 < z < 1\}$
Now I apply Fubini and get: $$\int_Afdm^3 = \int_{(0, 1)}\int_{(0, z)}\int_{(0, y)}x^2y^3z^4m(x)m(y)m(z) = \frac{1}{252}$$
Is this correct and are the steps I made valid? And how do I calculate the second one? Is there an easier way than working with the definition?
  ($H^k(E) = c \lim_{\delta\to 0}\inf\{\sum_{h}diam(F_h) : E \subset \cup_hF_h , diam(F_h) < \delta\}$, with $c$ a constant)

Comment: There is a theorem stating that $m^n=H^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Are you not allowed to use it?

Comment: @asdq I probably am, but I am pretty new to the Hausdorff measure, so I didnt know about that.

Comment: @asdq That isn't quite right.  The $n$-dimensional Lebesgue and Hausdorff dimensions agree *up to a multiplicative constant*.  They are normalized slightly differently (e.g. the Hausdorff measure of a unit ball is 1 in any dimension).

Comment: @XanderHenderson do you know how to calculate that integral?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Well this depends on how you define the Hausdorff measure. There are authors that define it such that it exactly matches the Lebesgue measure. Anyways, this does not really make a difference here as far as I can tell.

Comment: $m(B) = 0$ this implies  $H(B) = 0$ and therefore the integral is $0$?